# How to use spool command in sql developer oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, spool

Dears,
I cannot use spool command. It is not working or i am not doing something right.
I am trying to save query result in txt file (tried also csv saving with  `select /*csv*/ * from table`  but it also did not work).

So what i wrote is:

```
set echo off
set trimspool on
spool 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\clobams\Test1.txt'
select  pn, serial_number from stock ;
spool off;
```

And i am getting error when pressing `execute statement`   `ORA-00900:invalid SQL statement` . Sql works fine - when i execute only that part,it gives me output to the screen. How should i save my output to the file?

I have already tried to remove `set echo off` and `set trimspool on` but none of these helped

Comment: Why have you wrapped the file path in single quotes? Try removing them.

Comment: Just tried. Got same error: invalid SQL statement.

Comment: Click on the button next to execute ( Run script ) or simply press F5

Comment: Dear Kaushik, it works now! It was a  complex problem: firstly - no need of single quotes, secondly it was Run Script, which worked.

Comment: Do you know how it will be possible to extend saved result size? It has clob in it and now it trims to 4000 chars.

Comment: Use the set long to increase lob data returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what i have run on my sql developer:

```
spool C:\Users\**direcotory**\Desktop\old desktop\sql\Test1.txt;
select  *  from YOUR_TABLE;
spool off;
```

and i got output in file test1. you need to run all commands as script.

[image]