# SPOOL data from Oracle to workbook

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I have prepared SQL*Plus script, part of it is `SPOOL`of a tables to *.csv* files, so I started wondering if it's possible to create the excel workbook and add those to it using SQL?

I have tried `SPOOL` to *.xlsx* with `set sqlformat csv` but when i try to open it, it returns an error.

Thanks for the feedback

Comment: sqlcl doesn't spool to xls/xlsx. CSV creates a file with csv data.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49530512/5860789

Follow above answer of mine and use `".csv"` format instead of `".txt"`

Comment: Spool into .csv works fine for me, I've been wondering if i can take it further, and append it to workbook using SQL